# Linearizing a constraint containing a root square expression

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations, linear-programming

We are working on a combinatorial optimization problem. In order to solve it using CPLEX, we need to linearize the non-linear constraint stated in the following.

Let $p_i, i \in I$ denotes a set of positive continuous decision variables. $y_i, i \in I$, $x_{ji}, j \in J, i \in I$ are two sets of binary decision variables. How to **linearize** the following constraint:$$p_i y_i - \sum_{j \in  J}b_{j} x_{ji} \le \sqrt{\sum_{j \in  J} x_{ji}^2 \sigma_j^2}, \quad\quad\forall i \in I$$

where $b_{j}$ and $\sigma_j$ are positive known parameters of the problem.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: But what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, i have tried to square the expression wich gives: $(p_i y_i)^2 - 2 p_i y_i \sum_{j \in  J}b_{j} x_{ji} + (\sum_{j \in  J}b_{j} x_{ji})^2 \le \sum_{j \in  J} x_{ji} \sigma_j^2, \quad\quad\forall i \in I$ and here i'm stuck

Comment: Squaring inequalities can be tricky. It is not an equivalence relation. For example left hand side could be negative, but a square can never be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using cplex, there is no need to linearize really, all you need is a second-order cone model.

Write as
$$(p_i y_i - \sum_{j \in  J}b_{j} x_{ji}) \le t,~t \leq \sqrt{\sum_{j \in  J} x_{ji}^2 \sigma_j^2}$$
and square the nonlinear term (possible as the problematic term is non-negative, so there is no loss in generality to assume $t\geq 0$)
$$t^2 \leq \sum_{j \in  J} x_{ji}^2 \sigma_j^2$$
and use $x_{ji}^2 = x_{ji}$. From that, it follows that you have a convex quadratic constraint, i.e. second-order cone representable.

Comment: Are you sure we can't accidentally disqualify valid solutions by doing this? LHS could be negative and after squaring it becomes positive for sure, while RHS is always positive.

Comment: True, incorrect transformation, will adjust, think is salvageable